# PropTypes in functional stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

Without using class, how do I use PropTypes in functional stateless component of react?

```
export const Header = (props) => (
   <div>hi</div>
)
```

Answer (score 179):

The [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) show how to do this with ES6 component classes, but the same applies for stateless functional components.

Firstly, `npm install` / `yarn add` the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) package if you haven't already.

Then, add your `propTypes` (and `defaultProps` too if required) after the stateless functional component has been defined, before you export it.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Header = ({ name }) => <div>hi {name}</div>;

Header.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};

// Same approach for defaultProps too
Header.defaultProps = {
  name: "Alan"
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: What a benefit of doing that? It would work without defined propTypes as well.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was only for class components.

Comment: @Yarik By using propTypes you get some automatic checks done for you. You'll get a warning every time your code "breaks the contract".

Answer (score 32):

It isn't different with the stateful, You can add it like:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
Header.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string
}
```

Here is a link to [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) npm

Comment: Though if you're using more recent versions of React you'll want to import `PropTypes` on its own in which case you'll want to leave off `React`and just have `title: PropTypes.string`

Answer (score 2):

**It's done the same way you do with Class Based Components**

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

    const = function_name => {}

    function_name.propTypes = {
       prop_name : PropTypes.number
       . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    }
```

Hope This Helps !

Answer (score 1):

Same way you do in class based components:

```
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

   const funcName = (props) => {
       ...
   }
   funcName.propTypes = {
       propName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
   }
```

Note: You might have to install `prop-types` via `npm install prop-types` or `yarn add prop-types`, depending on the React version you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Since [React 15](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html), use `propTypes` to validate props and provide documentation this way:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const Header = (props={}) => (
   <div>{props}</div>
);
Header.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.object
};
```

This code on the assumption of default value `props={}` if no props provided to the component.