# React: PropTypes in stateless functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

In React, I wrote a stateless functional component and now want to add Prop Type validation to it.

`List` component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function List(props) {
  const todos = props.todos.map((todo, index) => (<li key={index}>{todo}</li>));
  return (<ul></ul>);
}

List.PropTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default List;
```

`App` component, rendering `List`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import List from './List';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (<List todos={this.state.todos} />);
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see in `App`, I am passing `this.state.todos` to `List`. Since `this.state.todos` is a string, I expected Prop Type validation to kick in. Instead, I get an error in the browser console because strings don't have a method called `map`.

Why is the Prop Type validation not working as expected? Takin a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582209/proptypes-in-functional-stateless-component), the case seems identical.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You should change the casing on the property to `propTypes`:

```
- List.PropTypes = {
+ List.propTypes = {
    todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };
```

**Correct**:

```js
List.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

(The *instance* of a PropTypes object is lowercase, but the Class/Type is uppercase. The instance is `List.propTypes`. The Class/Type is `PropTypes`.)

Comment: Quick and easy, thank you! I simply overlooked that, d'oh.

Comment: To illuminate this kind of dirty errors you can use https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-typos.md

Comment: For clarity, if anyone cares about the distinction, `List.propTypes` is *not* in fact an instance of `PropTypes`. It's a plain javascript object. In fact, `PropTypes` isn't even a class: it's also an object. Instance in this answer is not meant in the object-oriented sense.

Comment: Classes are objects